# Android ImageView Translate Animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I am trying to animate a ImageView, scaling it down, fading it out and translating it to the top-left corner of the screen.
This is what I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<alpha
android:fromAlpha = "1.0"
android:toAlpha = "0"
android:duration = "900">
</alpha>
<scale
android:fromXScale = "1.0"
android:toXScale = "0" 
android:fromYScale = "1.0"
android:toYScale = "0" 
android:pivotX="0%"
android:pivotY="0%" 
android:duration = "900">
</scale>

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:fromYDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="-50.0%p" android:toYDelta="-50.0%p" 

    android:duration="900" 
    android:fillAfter="true" 
    />
</set>
```

Scaling and fading works fine, but the translation is not accurate. I want it to go to the top left corner of the screen. How can I do that?

thanks!

Comment: How is your ImageView placed in the layout?  The translate animations are relative to the parent, so if the ImageView is in a parent that's centered to the layout, it won't go anywhere.

Comment: My ImageView is centered in a full-width/full-height framelayout.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move an object to the new coordinates once the animation is done. You see, the animation does not actually move the objects - it only animates the image.

Comment: Try to add code examples when you can Andre. Makes it easier for people to understand..